# spark parse element array and compare the relevant field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame like below, uinfo column is a array and I want to have the below condition 
1. When the first array element is **id.name** take second array element **user1** and column **id1** value and create a new data frame

2. if the **id1** value is **null** then take **id2** value

   ```
   +-----------------+----------+--------+-----+-------+
   |            uinfo           |   count| id1 |   id2 |
   +-----------------+----------+--------+-----+-------+
   |   [id.name, user1, example]|       1| aijk|   null|
   |   [id.name, user2]         |       3| null|   bcdk|
   |   [id.value, overflow]     |       6| 123k|   null|
   |   [id.name, user3]         |       7| klmn|   null|
   +-----------------+----------+--------+-----+-- ----+
   ```

so the final data frame should like below

```
+-----------------+--------------+                                                   
|   uinfo         |      customid|
+-----------------+--------------+
|   user1         |          aijk|
|   user2         |          bcdk|
|   user3         |          klmn| 
+-----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
df
.select(
  when($"uinfo"(0)==="id.name",$"uinfo"(1)).as("uinfo"),
  coalesce($"id1",$"id2").as("customid")
)
.where($"uinfo".isNotNull)
```

Comment: how to check when I have a more id fields to be checked against NULL , if id1 in null then id2 and if id2 null then id3 and if id3 is null id4

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution below

```
df.withColumn("customid",when(col("uinfo")(0) === "id.name" && !col("id1").isNull,col("id1")).otherwise(col("id2"))).withColumn("uinfo", when(col("uinfo")(0) === "id.name",col("uinfo")(1))).filter(!col("uinfo").isNull).drop("id1","id2","count").show
```

Comment: how to check when I have a more id fields to be checked against NULL , if id1 in null then id2 and if id2 null then id3 and if id3 is null id4